# Nao estou conseguindo dar print no javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Bem estou tentando fazer uma pagina de html simples em que o utilizador digita um número e depois a pagina mostra a tabuda do mesmo. So que não estou conseguindo fazer com que a pagina digite a tabuda, alguem pode me ajudar?

```
<header><h3>Tabuada</h3></header>
        <p><input type="number" name="n" id="n" placeholder="Digite um numero"></p>
        <p><button type="submit" onclick="tabuada()">Executar</button></p>
        <div id='tab' style='display:inline'></div>
    <script>
        function tabuada(){
            var resultado = document.getElementById('tab');
            var text = '';
            var num = parseInt(document.getElementById("n").value);
            for(var x=1; x<=10; x++){
                text += num+"x"+i+"="+num*i+"<br />";
            }
            resultado.innerHTML = text;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ao executar o seu código, é possível ver o erro ao clicar no botão `executar`.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined

Para resolver este problema basta utilizar a variável x.

Desta para consertar este problema basta utilizar a variável que está definida no corpo do laço de repetição `for`. No seu caso é a variável `x`.

```
for(var x=1; x<=10; x++){
   text += num+"x"+x+"="+num*x+"<br />"; //mudar 'i' para 'x'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No seu "for" você declarou o contador como "x" mas você esta usando ele como se fosse "i".

O correto seria trocar o "for" de:

```
for(var x=1; x<=10; x++)
```

Para:

```
for(var i=1; i<=10; i++)
```

O código completo ficaria assim:

```
<header><h3>Tabuada</h3></header>
        <p><input type="number" name="n" id="n" placeholder="Digite um numero"></p>
        <p><button type="submit" onclick="tabuada()">Executar</button></p>
        <div id='tab' style='display:inline'></div>
    <script>
        function tabuada(){
            var resultado = document.getElementById('tab');
            var text = '';
            var num = parseInt(document.getElementById("n").value);
            for(var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
                text += num+"x"+i+"="+num*i+"<br />";
            }
            resultado.innerHTML = text;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```